# rosjava publishing to a topic based on user input (button)

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been playing around with rosjava now for a few days and it is great. I am able to connect my android phone to ros master over usb/wifi and have them publish/subscribe to one another.

What I am trying to do now is add a button on my android app, when the user hits it, the message being published changes. To clarify: I have a publisher node "talkernode" created that starts by publishing a String "Hello" message on a "/chatter" topic. When the user hits a button, I want the String message to change to something of my choice.

Below is the relevant portion of my code. The `publishGo()` method is my onClick callback function, where I am trying to add code to change the message being published. I have already tested that something happens when the button is hit and it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends RosActivity{
Button btn;

public MainActivity() {
    super("Example", "Example");
}

@Override
public void startMasterChooser() {
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI("http://192.168.42.19:11311/");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
    }

    nodeMainExecutorService.setMasterUri(uri);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            MainActivity.this.init(nodeMainExecutorService);
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.robot_button);
}

@Override
protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
    Talker talkernode = new Talker(this);

    NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(
            InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress());
    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(getMasterUri());

    nodeMainExecutor.execute(talkernode, nodeConfiguration);
}

protected void publishGo(View view) {
    // Code here
}
}
```

Below is the Talker class code. `randomCommand` is the string being published and the string I want to change when the button is clicked.

```
class Talker extends AbstractNodeMain {
private String randomCommand = "Hello";
Talker(MainActivity mainActivity) {

}

@Override
public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
    return GraphName.of("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker");
}

@Override
public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
    final Log log = connectedNode.getLog();
    final Publisher<std_msgs.String> publisher =
            connectedNode.newPublisher("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
    // This CancellableLoop will be canceled automatically when the node shuts
    // down.
    connectedNode.executeCancellableLoop(new CancellableLoop() {
        @Override
        protected void setup() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {
            std_msgs.String str = publisher.newMessage();
            str.setData(randomCommand);
            log.info("I publish: \"" + randomCommand + "\"");
            publisher.publish(str);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    });

}
}
```

I apologize if this is an easy question or if it has been answered before, but any help would be immensely appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272979/rosjava-publishing-to-a-topic-based-on-user-input-(button)/) by [agkhalil](https://answers.ros.org/users/32232/agkhalil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@agkhalil what you need in this case is a publisher "on demand".

First of all, save the `publisher` object in a member variable in the node in the `onStart` method, so that you can use it later. You have to do this in `onStart` because the `ConnectedNode` provides you the publisher.

```
class Talker extends AbstractNodeMain {
Publisher<std_msgs.String> publisher;
(...)

@Override
public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
    publisher = connectedNode.newPublisher("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
    (...)
}
}
```

Second, add a `publish` method to your node that you can call whenever you want:

```
// Note that you shouldn't call this before onStart is called; 
// check that publisher is not null before using it!
public void publish(String message) {
    std_msgs.String toPublish = publisher.newMessage();
    toPublish.setData(message);
    publisher.publish(toPublish);
}
```

Then, just store your `Talker` node somewhere you can access from the callback button, and call `publish` from there. That should cover your use case. Remember that there is a period of time between the moment you create the node and the moment `onStart` is called; that's why you should be careful with the state of `publisher` member variable.

Bonus: Note that you can also make your publisher latched; if you do so, the publisher will publish the message to each new subscriber and you won't need to do anything else. To do so, after creating the publisher, do `publisher.setLatchMode(true)`.

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agkhalil](https://answers.ros.org/users/32232/agkhalil/) on 2017-10-13**:
Thanks a bunch man! It works!